# Why does AGDK not hitting my breakpoints on Debug? It does when I attach the process to a already running Android app session

Tags: android, game-engine, breakpoints, visual-studio-debugging

I started testing AGDK and went through their Quickstart guide https://developer.android.com/games/agde/quickstart
I also read myself through the Debugger section.

Starting the Sample project "teapot" was no problem on my USB connected phone, but I couldn't debug properly. My breakpoints won't get hit.

I tried to Attach to the running teapot app session of my phone like described in the Debugger Guide and my breakpoints got hit properly.

Why isn't it working when I just start the Debugger on my Phone? Visual Studio also says "Attach to Process.." while my Phone is waiting for the Debugger to attach and after a few seconds the app starts.

Comment: Hi David, is your issue solved?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have set the target project as startup project(right-click the project > Set as Startup Project), and have chosen `Debug` configuration in VS IDE. Also make sure you have done what this document: [*Enable Debugging on the Device*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/set-up-device-for-development#enable-debugging-on-the-device) mentioned and try to rebuild the project.

In addition, please try to set project properties > Build > Advanced Build Settings > Output > Debugging information to `Portable`.

Comment: Sry for my late reply. Thanks for your message.

I did have DebugGame as the configuration and my UnrealGame as the Startup Project setuped. I mean I already got breakpoints working when I attach to a running session on my Phone, but not when I start a session from VS.

I didn't find Project properties > Build > Advanced Build Settings > Output :S

Comment: Ok, did you meet the requirement of triggering something to hit the breakpoints? For example, if breakpoints are set for rotating codes of the teapot, until you rotate the teapot, the breakpoint will be hit. But I'm a little confused, as normally, for debugging, after clicking the "Start Debugging" button, VS will deploy the app and attach to the app to debug. Does VS/breakpoints report or warn some messages?